# перекосился Adminbar в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет!
[image]
Вот такой вид сейчас на странице контента, и не могу понять, то ли я какой файл случайно удалил, то ли изменил. В админке же всё отлично. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ссылку можно?
Пробовали освежить cache в браузере (ctrl-F5)?
Из комментария видел, что локально. Не думаю, что файл пропал. (А если пропал, тогда можно лечить перезалив все ядро - можно пробовать.)
Скорее всего идет борьба по какому-то классу CSS. Попробуйте изучать admin-bar в инструментах браузера.

Comment: Локалка. Пробовал.